# Extract Items from IEnumerable using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I wanna do something like that:

```
var listItems = new List<someType>;

items.Method(i=>listItems.enqueue(i));
```

I bet it's so simple.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what exactly you're trying to do: What is `items`? What does `Method` do? What results do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `ForEach`, which is on IList, so you need `items.ToList().ForEach(i => listItems.Add(i));`

Comment: sorry i noticed the question would be understood wrong so i edited it

Comment: or to escape unnecessary operation write your own extension public static void Foreach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Action act) { foreach(T item in src) act.Invoke(item);}}

Comment: thank you , and im realy sorry about the misleading, i just couldnt edit the question fast to fix it

Answer (score 4):

Your scenario looks straightforward enough that you could use the [List.AddRange method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx):

```
listItems.AddRange(items);
```

In case you're wondering, a `List<T>` has a [ForEach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx), but such a method doesn't exist for `IEnumerable<T>`. You can read more about that in Eric Lippert's blog post: ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx). Thus, I recommend you take advantage of `listItems` being a `List<T>` and using the `AddRange` method as opposed to converting `items` to a `List<T>` simply to use `ForEach` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but I think, that you are asking about lists substraction. For, example you have two lists `list1` and `list2` and you desire to substract items of `list2` from `list1`. In this case you should act as follow:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list1.Add(1);
list1.Add(2);
list1.Add(3);
list1.Add(4);
list1.Add(5);

list2.Add(2);
list2.Add(4);

List<int> list3 = list1.Where(i => list2.IndexOf(i) == -1).Select(i => i).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, i was asking about foreach method